# ckeditor soft return (shift-return) adds unknown character to HTML?

Tags: ckeditor

When using shift-return to add a soft return to ckeditor (version 4.5.3), and the resulting HTML is converted to PDF via wkhtmltopdf, there are "?" characters that are sometimes inserted at the start of the lines with soft returns.

Examining the HTML source, I find that there are 3 hidden characters inserted that wkhtmltopdf is converting to "?" since it doesn't know what to do with them. These characters don't show up in Notepad++ when "Show hidden characters" is turned on, but examining the file with a hex editor shows the are hex codes:

E2 80 8B

Why does ckeditor insert these hidden characters when you use a soft break, in addition to the `<br />` tag? What is their purpose? And more importantly, is there a way I can disable this behavior? Or perhaps this is a bug?

**UPDATE**

I have duplicated the behavior using the current [online ckeditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo).

Type a few characters (like "asdf") on several lines, using shift-return to do a soft return between each line. Then click on the "Source" button to view the HTML. Select and copy an area large enough to more than fully contain the area you typed (make sure to copy a little extra below what you added). Then paste it into an online hex editor:

https://hexed.it/

You will see the same characters:

E2 80 8B

Please let me know if this is a bug. If not, what can I do to disable this behavior?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but it seems to work fine, so it might be your browser or your OS. Can you provide better reproduction steps?

Comment: It's a zero width space, by the way, U+200B. Not a hidden character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ckeditor bug report area, I was informed that the correct way to get "clean" HTML from ckeditor is to use:

```
editor.getData();
```

NOT what I was using:

```
editor.document.getBody().getHtml();
```

Posting here so others can easily find this, as the ckeditor documentation doesn't really help much.